# Question for Unity3d Developement platform:'NatUtility' does not contain a definition for 'DeviceLost'

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, portforwarding, nat, network-connection

I already added `using Mono.Nat;` but apparently Unity said

> 'NatUtility' does not contain a definition for 'DeviceLost'"

which confuses me. To the point where I literally copied 1:1 with the API Reference. I'm quite in  confusion.

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mono.Nat;

public class UPnP_PortForwardingBS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // Hook into the events so you know when a router has been detected or has gone offline
        NatUtility.DeviceFound += DeviceFound;
        NatUtility.DeviceLost += DeviceLost;

        // Start searching for upnp enabled routers
        NatUtility.StartDiscovery();
    }

    void DeviceFound(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
    {
        // This is the upnp enabled router
        INatDevice device = args.Device;

        // Create a mapping to forward external port 3000 to local port 1500
        device.CreatePortMap(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 1500, 3000));

        // Retrieve the details for the port map for external port 3000
        Mapping m = device.GetSpecificMapping(Protocol.Tcp, 3000);

        // Get all the port mappings on the device and delete them
        foreach (Mapping mp in device.GetAllMappings())
            device.DeletePortMap(mp);

        // Get the external IP address
        var externalIP = device.GetExternalIP();
    }

    private void DeviceLost(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
    {
        INatDevice device = args.Device;

        //Debug.Log("Device Lost");
        //Debug.Log("Type: {0}", device.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see **Mono.Nat** GitHub [release](https://github.com/alanmcgovern/Mono.Nat/releases) page:

> - Removed NatUtility.DeviceLost as it was never a usable event.
> - Added the ability to manually pass messages into Mono.Nat if another part of the application has already bound to the normal upnp
>   listening port.
> - Improved logging via Logger.Factory
> - Searchers are disposed when NatUtility.StopDiscovery is invoked, and (re-)created when NatUtility.StartDiscovery is invoked. In
>   addition any previously detected devices are cleared when
>   StopDiscovery is invoked.